# Solving ON DELETE CASCADE cycles with triggers on MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, trigger, foreign-key, delete, cascade

I have code that is working fine in PostgreSQL and I now have to port it to MS SQL Server. It involves tables with potential cycles on delete/update events and SQL Server is complaining about it:

```
-- TABLE t_parent
CREATE TABLE t_parent (m_id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, m_name nvarchar(450));

-- TABLE t_child
CREATE TABLE t_child (m_id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, m_name nvarchar(450),
    id_parent int CONSTRAINT fk_t_child_parent FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES t_parent(m_id)
    --ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

-- TABLE t_link
CREATE TABLE t_link (m_id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    id_parent int CONSTRAINT fk_t_link_parent FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES t_parent(m_id)
    -- ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
    , id_child int CONSTRAINT fk_t_link_child FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES t_child(m_id)
    -- ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
    , link_name nvarchar(450));
```

I have commented out the `ON DELETE/UPDATE` constraints that were accepted by PostgreSQL, which show the exact behavior I'm trying to reproduce in MS SQL Server, otherwise I'm getting the error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'fk_t_link_child' on table 't_link' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

So I removed them (equivalent to `NO ACTION` from [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)) and decided to go the trigger way (as hinted by [several sites](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2733/solving-the-sql-server-multiple-cascade-path-issue-with-a-trigger/)) to delete related `t_link` rows when the related `t_parent` is deleted:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_delete_CASCADE_t_link_id_parent ON t_parent AFTER DELETE AS BEGIN
    DELETE FROM t_link WHERE id_parent IN (SELECT m_id FROM DELETED)
END;
```

What I'm trying to have overall is:

- all `t_child` records deleted when their related `t_parent` record is deleted (`ON DELETE CASCADE`), and `t_link` records related to deleted `t_child` deleted as well
- all `t_link` records deleted when their related `t_parent` record is deleted (`ON DELETE CASCADE`)
- `t_link.id_child` set to `NULL` when their related `t_child` record is deleted  *or* deleted as well, if it makes things easier (`ON DELETE SET NULL` or `ON DELETE CASCADE`)

Then I insert a few test data and try :

```
insert into t_parent (m_name) values('toto');
insert into t_link (id_parent, id_child, link_name) values (1, NULL, 'chan');
delete from t_parent where m_id = 1;
```

> ERROR: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "fk_t_link_parent". The conflict occurred in database "DBTest", table "dbo.t_link", column 'id_parent'.

I'm guessing the problem is my trigger is not called because it happens *after* the delete itself, which fails with the above message; and there is no `BEFORE DELETE` trigger type (which would sound like something I'd like to have).

Now I have to say that the SQL is all generated by a Java JPA-like program that has to cope with the different DBMS (one subclass for PostgreSQL, one for SQL Server, ...) so I should stay generic: I can't put `ON DELETE CASCADE` constraints on one table and use triggers (or any other method you might know) with others (I could, but at the cost of a code over-complexification that I'm trying to avoid).

The SQL Server is a [Docker image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker?view=sql-server-2017&pivots=cs1-bash) so I'm not sure I could have debug output somewhere (unless in `sqlcmd` command). If it's of any relevance, the version is 2017.

The only way out of this I see is just dropping the reference constraint and handle it all manually with triggers. But then: what's the point in having foreign key constraints?

---

**EDIT**: After [David's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/251794/71437), I should clarify a few points:

The `CREATE TABLE` and `CREATE TRIGGER` SQL is generated by code, each time a new table is to be added (from an SQL-agnostic configuration file). As SQL Server can refuse to create `ON DELETE CASCADE` constraints due to potential cycles, I decided to just indicate the `FOREIGN KEY` constraint and then have each table referencing `t_parent` create a `FOR DELETE` trigger, each performing the CASCADE or SET NULL operation on its own rows.

The suggested `INSTEAD OF DELETE` trigger is definitely the mechanics I'm looking for, but only a single instance of such trigger can be created for a table (which makes sense) so I didn't go that way.

I might end up creating stored procedures instead of my current triggers, and update the INSTEAD OF trigger each time a new referencing table (and procedure) is added, calling each stored procedure.

Answer (score 4):

You're close.  `AFTER` triggers happen *after* foreign key constraint checking.  So you need an `INSTEAD OF` trigger.  That way you can modify the child tables before performing the DELETE on the target table.

eg

```
-- TABLE t_parent
CREATE TABLE t_parent 
(
  m_id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
  m_name nvarchar(450)
);

-- TABLE t_child
CREATE TABLE t_child 
(
    m_id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
    m_name nvarchar(450),
    id_parent int CONSTRAINT fk_t_child_parent FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES t_parent(m_id)
      ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

-- TABLE t_link
CREATE TABLE t_link (m_id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    id_parent int CONSTRAINT fk_t_link_parent FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES t_parent(m_id)
      ON DELETE NO ACTION
    , id_child int CONSTRAINT fk_t_link_child FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES t_child(m_id)
      ON DELETE CASCADE
    , link_name nvarchar(450));


    go

CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER trg_delete_CASCADE_t_link_id_parent 
ON t_parent INSTEAD OF DELETE 
AS 
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON
    DELETE FROM t_link WHERE id_parent IN (SELECT m_id FROM DELETED);
    DELETE FROM t_parent WHERE m_id IN (SELECT m_id FROM DELETED);

END;

go

insert into t_parent (m_name) values('toto');
insert into t_link (id_parent, id_child, link_name) values (1, NULL, 'chan');
delete from t_parent where m_id = 1;
```

This way t_parent->t_child->t_link uses CASCADE DELETES, and t_parent->t_link is handled by the INSTEAD OF trigger.

Comment: I tried the INSTEAD OF DELETE trigger calling stored procedures (each handling deletion for a specific table: one for t_child, one for t_link), but the order I call the procedures matters because of the FOREIGN KEY constraint (i.e. I should call the t_link before the t_child, which makes sense). I (sadly) decided to remove all constraints and [handle it all in `AFTER DELETE` triggers](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/251887/71437).

Answer (score 2):

For simplicity in the SQL generator, I ended up dropping all foreign key constraints and used `AFTER DELETE` triggers on tables to better address deletion of `t_link` records (I want to delete them when their `parent` *and* `child` are deleted/NULL):

```
CREATE TABLE t_parent (m_id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
    m_name NVARCHAR(450));
```

`t_child` table looses it `CONSTRAINT xxx FOREIGN KEY`, replaced with an `AFTER DELETE` trigger:

```
CREATE TABLE t_child (m_id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
    id_parent INT,
    m_name NVARCHAR(450));

-- ON DELETE SET NULL equivalent
CREATE TRIGGER trg_delete_nulls_t_child_t_parent ON t_parent AFTER DELETE AS BEGIN
    UPDATE t_child SET id_parent = NULL WHERE id_parent IN (SELECT m_id FROM DELETED);
END;
```

Same for `t_link`, which is an `ON DELETE SET NULL` promoted to `CASCADE` if both `id_parent` *and* `id_child` are NULL (i.e. deleted/non-existent):

```
CREATE TABLE t_link (m_id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    id_parent INT, id_child INT,
    link_name NVARCHAR(450));

-- Trigger ON DELETE SET NULL when t_parent is deleted, or ON DELETE CASCADE if no linked t_child
CREATE TRIGGER trg_delete_nulls_t_link_t_parent ON t_parent AFTER DELETE AS BEGIN
    -- "Promotion" to CASCADE if id_child is also NULL
    DELETE FROM t_link WHERE id_child IS NULL AND id_parent IN (SELECT m_id FROM DELETED);
    -- ON DELETE SET NULL (that might not be triggered if the previous statement has deleted all the records)
    UPDATE t_link SET id_parent = NULL WHERE id_parent IN (SELECT m_id FROM DELETED);
END;

-- Same for t_child deletions vs. t_parent
CREATE TRIGGER trg_delete_nulls_t_link_t_child ON t_child AFTER DELETE AS BEGIN
    UPDATE t_link SET id_child = NULL WHERE id_child IN (SELECT m_id FROM DELETED);
    DELETE FROM t_link WHERE id_parent IS NULL AND id_child IN (SELECT m_id FROM DELETED);
END;
```

Of course, that is probably less efficient than having hand-crafted constraints, but it's good enough (so far) for my use-case and simplifies the SQL generator code *a lot*.

I guess there are some "gray" behaviors e.g. when a record `id_child` is deleted (`DELETE FROM t_link ...`) and then NULLed by the next line (`UPDATE t_link SET id_child=NULL`), especially with regards to transactions, but it seems to work on my unit tests.